# Cannot invoke sendData

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am getting the error below while attempting to send the current time of a song however I get this error, but it says that the first argument is supposed to be of type NSObject I am pretty sure

```
Cannot invoke sendData with an argument list of type '(NSTimeInterval!, toPeers: [AnyObject]!, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode)' 

func hostPhoneTime(){
    //songTime is of type NSTimeInterval!
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(songTime_, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable)



}
```

Comment: What are the arguments of the function supposed to be (what does the documentation say?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCSession/sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:) says it is a NSData, check it out

**Edit**:

Here's an example of how you can transform a value like a NSIntervalTime (which is a Double) to a NSData

```
var time: NSTimeInterval = 112
// it's easier to parse your data to a String first
var timeString = "\(time)" 
// then this is how you get a NSData
let timeData = timeString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

// Let's imagine here you send your NSData to another place like a socket or something that receives NSData

// Your transform it back to a string
var receivedTimeString = NSString(data: timeData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
// And finally to your desired type
var receivedTime: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Double(receivedTimeString as String)!)
```

Comment: I cannot find the documentation to encoding and decoding especially for NSObjects, would you mind helping me find the link or explaining it for me?